# Post request with springboot json format

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have a product table, I have a second option table. I cannot manage to create my options for the product at the same time as I create the product. I tried to create the options individually by creating an option table and a category join table. When I send the options in json format it doesn't work. I get the bad request error and in the console:

> JSON parse error: Cannot construct instance of
> `com.pastrycertified.cda.dto.OptionsDto` (although at least one
> Creator exists): no String-argument constructor/factory method to
> deserialize from String value('pie'); nested exception is
> com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot
> construct instance of `com.pastrycertified.cda.dto.OptionsDto`
> (although at least one Creator exists): no String-argument
> constructor/factory method to deserialize from String value
> ('pie') at [Source:
> (org.springframework.util.StreamUtils$NonClosingInputStream); line: 2,
> column: 19] (through reference chain:
> java.util.LinkedHashMap["typeOption"])]

Thank you for help

data

```
{
    "typeOption": "product",
    "ingredients": {
        "option1": "test",
        "option2":"test1"
    }
}
```

controller option

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/options")
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class OptionsController {

    private final OptionsService optionsService;

    @PostMapping("/")
    public void save(
            @RequestBody Map<String, OptionsDto > options
    ) {
        return ResponseEntity.ok(optionsService.save(options));
    }
}
```

optionService

```
public interface OptionsService {

    Options save(OptionsDto options);
}
```

optionServiceImpl

```
@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class OptionsServiceImpl implements OptionsService {


    @Override
    public Options save(OptionsDto options) {

        Options option = OptionsDto.toEntity(options);
        option.setTypeOption(option.getTypeOption());
        option.setIngredients(option.getIngredients());

        return option;
    }
}
```

optionDto

```
@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
@Builder
public class OptionsDto {

    private Integer id;

    private String typeOption;

    private String ingredients;

    private String nameCategory;

    private CategoryDto category;

    public static OptionsDto fromEntity(Options options) {

        return OptionsDto.builder()
                .id(options.getId())
                .typeOption(options.getTypeOption())
                .ingredients(options.getIngredients())
                .nameCategory(options.getCategory().getName())
                .build();
    }

    public static Options toEntity(OptionsDto options) {

        return Options.builder()
                .id(options.getId())
                .typeOption(options.getTypeOption())
                .ingredients(options.getIngredients())
                .build();
    }
}
```

Comment: can you share the json please?

Comment: The first part of the error messages say, that you should add a non argument constructor to your class: `public OptionsDto(){}`

Comment: thank you for your answer Jens , I updated my post I put the json format

Comment: `ingredients` is a string in your `OptionsDto`, but not in the json

Comment: Thank you for the answer Jens. Would you please have a link that explains the sending of a json or how to configure ingredient in the dto so that it receives a json? sorry I recently started with springboot

Comment: It is not primarely   spring boot, it is the onject mapping in the json library. As I understand your json correctly, `ingredients` must be a `Map<String,String>`

Comment: I tried to modify but I couldn't @Jens

Comment: why can't you modify?

Comment: Also the json you post does not fit to  the expected struture: `Map<String, OptionsDto > options`

Comment: I am a little lost. Do you have an example to show me please?

Comment: It is hard, becuase i do not know which is correct, your example json or your code snipped

Comment: It doesn't matter, I'll continue my research :) . Thank you for the time you took to try to help me :).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/251335/discussion-between-jens-and-tony).

Comment: Thanks for help
 de jens I succeeded thank you

Answer (score 0):

As Jens mentioned, you need a default constructor in the OptionDto class. Also, you must decide whether `ingredients` is a String or a Map.

In the controller, you are asking for a Map<> but what you pass in the JSON is not a map. Your controller must be asking for an OptionsDto and not a Map.

Comment: Thank you for help @Kristiyan Mihov . I added the annotation: AllArgsConstructor and NoArgsConstructor. I also removed the map